# Unicode character look-up

Tags: symbols, unicode

Now that I have switched to primarily using `XeTeX`, I find I do not use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) to find symbols very much. However, I often still need to locate symbols. Frequently I find myself looking through character lists for individual fonts or browsing through dingbat collections On-line.

- Is there a handwritten symbol recognition tool for Unicode?
- Is there a search tool that helps find dingbats among the numerous available fonts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Linux, there are two nice character selectors, [KCharSelect](http://utils.kde.org/projects/kcharselect/) for KDE,

[image: KCharSelect screenshot]

and [Gucharmap](https://live.gnome.org/Gucharmap) for GNOME,

[image: Gucharmap screenshot]

You can browse the various characters by script or Unicode block, or search by character description. Both programs are very nice, but personally, I prefer KCharSelect, as it has an incremental search bar which makes it faster to find the characters you need, and it displays *all* the information about a character, without you having to switch between the glyph ťab and the character information tab.

For Windows, you can use the built-in [Character Map](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_charmap.mspx?mfr=true) program, which supports Unicode in later versions of Windows:

[image]

Answer (score 32):

For recognising characters, [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) is very similar to [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but for unicode. I think this is what you're looking for.

Tables of characters are still useful when broken down properly. For example, if you're looking for a table of dingbats, then you can get that. All things unicode can be found from [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/charts/), surprisingly enough! This link will take you directly to the library of charts.

Comment: @eudoxos: No problem! ;)

Answer (score 10):

Such tools may depend on your OS.  On the Mac, there is something called the Character Viewer, which allows you to view all the Unicode characters either by character groupings or by code points.  For any particular character, it will then display all of the fonts on your system that contain that particular character, and allows you to insert the character into an open document.

[image: Character viewer]

Comment: It saddens me that Apple pretty much broke the wonderful character palette window in Lion `:-(`. For instance, there's no glyph view anymore, which makes it very difficult (if not impossible) to locate certain characters.

Comment: On Mac OS X there's also a standalone application called [UnicodeChecker](http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/).

Comment: @morbusg I don't have Lion on any of my machines, but [this blog post](http://www.masteryourmac.net/master-your-mac-blog/inserting-apple-special-characters-into-text-in-lion.html) seems to show a glyph view.

Comment: @AlanMunn: ah, localization might have confused things here a little: on my finnish localized Leopard, I have an option inside the menu called “View” (in your picture above), called “Glyyfi”, which shows a font-specific view of the glyphs. *That* has been removed from Lion.

Comment: @morbusg — I agree, it is really unfortunate. On the bright side, the Snow Leopard application actually runs fine under Lion. You can copy it from a 10.6 system. The path to the application is `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app`

Comment: @ToddLehman: That's great, thanks for the info! Although, there are so many other things changed for the worse, IMHO, that I might actually downgrade the whole system to Leopard (I want the old Exposé, for example).